# AIME I 2008 #13 solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

This is the problem.

[image]

That's the entire given solution.

[image]

This is the part I'm confused about.

Essentially, he used the zeroes of the function to express the coefficients in terms of each other and condensed the polynomial. Makes sense, and I got only this far. However, in the line where he says $x(1-x)(1+x)=y(1-y)(1+y)$ (Eq1), I don't understand why he's equating these two. Can someone explain the justification for that?

In the next line(Eq2), given that Eq1 is true, I understand is taken from $3a_1+3a_2+2a_4=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want $$x(1-x)(1+x) a_1 + y(1-y)(1+y)a_2 + xy(1-x) a_4 = 0.$$

You have used all the information given in the problem already to write the polynomial $p$ in terms of only three coefficients $a_1, a_2, a_4$ satisfying $$3 a_1 + 3 a_2 + 2 a_4 = 0.$$
With only this information, you can only look for $x$ and $y$ such that the triple $x(1-x)(1+x)$, $y(1-y)(1+y)$, and $xy(1-x)$ have ratio $3:3:2$.

It is possible that a particular polynomial $p$ may have other zeros of the form $(a/c, b/c)$ etc., but the problem is asking for a zero that works for **all** such $p$. Since you've already used all the information characterizing $p$, the above is all you can do.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHH I GET IT. it clicked!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The given condition should be true for **all** polynomials with the then derived relation

- $3a_1+3a_2+2a_4=0$

So, it must be true specifically for

- $a_1 = 1, a_2 =-1, a_4 = 0$ and
- $a_1 = 2, a_2 =0, a_4 = -3$.

These two sets of values give the two equations.

**Comment:**

It might be worth noting that $\begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\\-3\end{pmatrix}$ form a basis of the solutions of $3a_1+3a_2+2a_4=0$. This means, for the coefficients of all admissible polynomials you have:
$$\begin{pmatrix}a_1\\a_2\\a_4\end{pmatrix} = s\begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}{1}\\\color{blue}{-1}\\0\end{pmatrix}+t\begin{pmatrix}\color{blue}{2}\\0\\\color{blue}{-3}\end{pmatrix} \mbox{ with } s,t \in \mathbb{R}$$
So, you get
$$x(1-x)(1+x) a_1 + y(1-y)(1+y)a_2 + xy(1-x) a_4 = s(\color{blue}{1}x(1-x)(1+x) \color{blue}{-1} y(1-y)(1+y)) + t(\color{blue}{2}x(1-x)(1+x) \color{blue}{- 3}xy(1-x))$$

From this you can see that any solution to the two specific equations above is a solution for all polynomials satisfying the condition $3a_1+3a_2+2a_4=0$.